# row_number() from dplyr: An example with vector

Tags: r, dplyr

I don't understand this example from the `dplyr` help for `row_numbr()` using `?row_number()`.

```
library(dplyr)
x <- c(5, 1, 3, 2, 2, NA)
row_number(x)
[1]  5  1  4  2  3 NA
```

Why is the result not `c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)`? With `mtcars`:

```
mtcars %>% 
  select(mpg, cyl) %>% 
  mutate(row_num = row_number()) %>% 
  head()
```

which just gives the row number:

```
   mpg cyl row_num
1 21.0   6       1
2 21.0   6       2
3 22.8   4       3
4 21.4   6       4
5 18.7   8       5
6 18.1   6       6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at `help("row_number")`, then you can find that:

> row_number(): equivalent to rank(ties.method = "first")

Moreover, as you vector contains also NA, it should be noted that:

> x (is) a vector of values to rank. Missing values are left as is. If
>   you want to treat them as the smallest or largest values, replace with
>   Inf or -Inf before ranking.

What can be used instead is:

```
seq_along(x)

[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Comment: I still don't get it. Why does it then produce row numbers when used inside `mutate` when no arguments...

Comment: Also this does not work: `mtcars %>% mutate(r = rank(ties.method = "first"))`

Comment: If you are applying it on a vector as in your example, then it behaves like `rank()`. If you are using it without specifying the parameters inside `mutate()`, then it essentially behaves like `1:nrow(df)`. Similarly, `rank()` is not working as you are not specifying an `x` parameter.

Comment: I have accepted the answer but I am still a bit confused. I guess I have to think more about it. Thanks.

Comment: You just need to consider the context in which you are applying this function :)

Comment: I have just asked a new question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60724037/fatal-error-with-min-rank-inside-mutate-with-a-data-frame)