# Fatal error with min_rank inside mutate with a data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to practice window functions and just want to experiment with this code but my R session aborts when I run this code:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
  select(mpg, cyl) %>% 
  mutate(r = min_rank())
```

If these functions behave differently depending if context is a `df` or vector how should we know what they do? All the examples are for vectors... E.g. `row_number()`behaves differently on a data frame compared to a vector.

Comment: `row_number()` behaves differently in the case of a vector and a df, however, the other rank functions require a `x` parameter.

Comment: They shouldnt crash R like this. I can reproduce this on two machines. Report a bug to the maintainers of dplyr.

Comment: @Spacedman: great thanks I will report on github!